# Is firasat al mo'min -the believers- (فِرَاسَة المؤمين) the same as what in the west is called empaths?

Tags: metaphysical

Salam alaykum,

Definition of an empath: someone highly sensitive to their environments and intuition I.e. they have knowledge of things and places kind of like psychics but without use of jinns as in the case of some soothsayers etc.

I know of a similar concept in Islam

> رواه الترمذي في (جامعه)، الترمذي (3127) وغيره، وهو حديث لا يصح مرفوعا، وإنما هو قول عمرو بن أبي قيس: كان يقال: "اتقوا..." فذكره. انظر العقيلي (4/129) (1)، وقال: حديث غريب. ولفظه: عن أبي سعيد الخدري قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: "اتقوا فِرَاسَة المؤمن؛ فإنه ينظر بنور الله"، ثم قرأ: {إِنَّ فِي ذَلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّلْمُتَوَسِّمِينَ} (2)قد ذكر ابن القيم رحمه الله في (الطرق الحكمية) من أنواع الفراسة وأفرادها أشياء عجيبة، وقال في (تاج العروس شرح القاموس) (4): والفراسة -بالكسر- اسم من التفرس، وهو التوسم، يقال: تفرس فيه الشيءَ إذا توسمه. وقال ابن القَطَّاع: الفراسةُ بالعينِ إدراكُ الباطن، وبه فسر الحديث: "اتقوا فراسة المؤمن؛ فإنه ينظر بنور الله"، وقال الصاغاني: لم يثبت، قال ابن الأثير يقال بمعنيين: أحدهما: ما دل ظاهر الحديث عليه، وهو ما يوقعه الله تعالى في قلوب أوليائه؛ فيعلمون أحوال بعض الناس بنوع من الكرامات، وإصابة الظن، والحدس. والثاني: نوع يعلم بالدلائل، والتجارب، والخَلْق، والأخلاق، فتعرف به أحوال الناس، وللناس فيه تآليف قديمة وحديثة.
>
> وقال ابن القيم رحمه الله تعالى في (مدارج السالكين) في الكلام على الفراسة (5): قال تعالى: {إِنَّ فِي ذَلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّلْمُتَوَسِّمِينَ} ... فإن الناظر متى نظر في آثار ديار المكذبين، ومنازلهم، وما آل إليه أمرهم، أورثه ذلك فراسة، وعِبرة، وفكرة. وقال تعالى في حق المنافقين: {وَلَوْ نَشَاءُ لأَرَيْنَاكَهُمْ فَلَعَرَفْتَهُم بِسِيمَاهُمْ وَلَتَعْرِفَنَّهُمْ فِي لَحْنِ الْقَوْلِ} (6)، فالأول: فراسة النظر والعين، والثاني: فراسة الأذن والسمع. وسمعت شيخ الإسلام ابن تيمية رحمه الله يقول: عَلَّقَ معرفتَه إياهم بالنظر على المشيئة، ولم يعلق تعريفهم بلحن خطابهم على شرطٍ، بل أخبر به خبرا مؤكَّدًا بالقسم، فقال: {وَلَتَعْرِفَنَّهُمْ فِي لَحْنِ الْقَوْلِ}، وهو تعريض الخطاب، وفحوى الكلام، ومغزاه. واللحن ضربان: صواب، وخطأ، فلحن الصواب: نوعان، أحدهما: الفطنة، ومنه الحديث: "ولعل بعضَكم أن يكون أَلْْحَنَ بحجته من بعض" (7)، والثاني: التعريض والإشارة، وهو قريب من الكناية
>   [http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/22891/حول-حديث-اتقوا-فراسة-المؤمن](http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/22891/%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A4%D9%85%D9%86) (Source )

P.S. Couldn't find an English version so you would have to run a translation on Google if your Arabic is poor.

Answer (score 2):

First I strongly recommend you to look for the meanings of [فِرَاسَة](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9/) which might mean insight, perspicacity, foresight and wisdom in planing ...

A fast search gave that the science of firasah [علم الفراسة](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9) is translated into [Physiognomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiognomy):

> Physiognomy (from the Gk. physis meaning "nature" and gnomon meaning "judge" or "interpreter") is the assessment of a person's character or personality from his or her outer appearance, especially the face. The term can also refer to the general appearance of a person, object, or terrain, without reference to its implied characteristics, as in the physiognomy of an individual plant (see plant life-form) or of a plant community (see vegetation).

While [Empathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy) is the capacity to understand or feel what another person is experiencing or the ability to place oneself in another's position.

So if you read the biography of Imam Malik or a-Shafi'i you would have known that Imam Malik anticipated that a-Shafi'i would get some kind of fame. This doesn't mean that he could place himself in his students position but based on his students character and personality conclude or foresee ton some extent what they would make of him in the future! This is one of the meanings given to firasah.

Here some hopefully helpful links about this science (all in Arabic):

[An article](http://alwafd.org/%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1/985138-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%88%D9%83%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D9%83%D8%AB%D8%B1%D8%A9) from al-Wafd.
[An article](http://personalityanalysistest.com/ar/%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%AE%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84/) on this science.
[An article](http://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85_%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A9) with the title: learn the science of al-firasah.
[A Fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/132035) on whether it is allowed to learn this science.
[A link](http://readne.com/book/1482) to a book which is asigned to Imam a-Shafi'i on the matter.
And [a link](http://www.arageek.com/2015/06/29/best-books-in-the-science-of-ferasa.html) describing other works on the matter. I assume that your quotes are from the book of ibn al-Qayyim.

And finally [a link](http://sunnah.com/urn/741450) to the hadith you posted in your Question from Jami' at-Tirmidhi!

Comment: Jazakallah khairun do you know any literature where I can read on علم الفراسة؟