# Does Islam teach that what a man says will manifest into reality?

Tags: allah, christianity, comparative-religions

In Christianity they have what is called the "gift of prophecy", and in this gift, a man can say a saying and God will turn into what the man said. Does Islam teach it in its doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

The verses like the one you mentioned from surat [Yasin:82](http://legacy.quran.com/36/82) "kun fa yakun" meaning something like "be and it is" are quoting Allahs will, so in first place it has nothing to do with humans.

As Muslims believe that Muhammad is the last Prophet (based on [33:40](http://legacy.quran.com/33/40) ) nobody is able to come with a prophecy after him and if he pretended so he is considered a liar (Read also [this](https://islamqa.info/en/113393) related fatwa).

---

If somebody now came and say hey he's the last Prophet but not the last Messenger:
([5:3](http://legacy.quran.com/5/3)) also make an end saying that Islam is the final religion by saying:

> ...  This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved for you Islam as religion. But whoever is forced by severe hunger with no inclination to sin - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

Verse ([2:23](http://legacy.quran.com/2/23)) is further challenging those who disbelieve if they don't believe that Muhammad is the final Messenger and Prophet to come with something similar. While verse ([2:79](http://legacy.quran.com/2/79)) is warning those who write a scripture and attribute it falsely to Allah. While finally verse ([15:9](http://legacy.quran.com/15/9)) is an emphasized promise of Allah to preserve the Quran (the final scripture).

---

This doesn't exclude that some people have been given some kind of gifts by Allah. For example abu Bakr told the gender of the children in his wife's womb or 'Omar warned an army ([The Hadith regarding "Ya Sariyya al-jabal", is it authentic or daif or False](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30412/the-hadith-regarding-ya-sariyya-al-jabal-is-it-authentic-or-daif-or-false)). Some scholars use the word karamah (For details and a definition read [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/124838), examples can be found in [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/175604)).

What might at least approach what you might mean are two things one is having dreams that come true which is reported in some ahadith to be a 1/46 of prophecy or prophet-hood see for example this hadith quoting how Muhammad got in touch with revelation from sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/urn/182960) and a longer version from sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:160a) and different versions and examples of the hadith narration about that dreams of good people are part of the prophet-hood from Sahih Muslim on the authority of [abu Hurairah](http://sunnah.com/muslim/42/15) and [ibn 'Omar](http://sunnah.com/muslim/42/20) and from sahih al-Bukahri on the authorithy of [Anas ibn Malik](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/2).

There are other ahadith less known quoting other parts of prophecy is [this one](http://sunnah.com/urn/418060) from Muwatta' Malik which is also quoted in sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/4).

And what Arabs call firasah فِرَاسَة, which is to a very basic extent explained here [Is firasat al mo'min -the believers- (فِرَاسَة المؤمين) the same as what in the west is called empaths?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/is-firasat-al-momin-the-believers-%d9%81%d9%90%d8%b1%d9%8e%d8%a7%d8%b3%d9%8e%d8%a9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d8%a4%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%86-the-same-as-what-in-the)

Anything else wouldn't go ahead with the teachings of Islam.