# Man entering the court of Imam Uthman

Tags: history, authenticity, mumin

What is the authenticity and the course of the following narration:

> A man [supposed his name is known] has entered the court of Imam
>   Uthman (may Allah be pleased with him), and Imam Uthman said: You
>   people arrive in my court in such a state that your eyes are ﬁlled
>   with fornication [zina].
>
> Shocked, the man asked whether has revelation started again, and was
>   responded that that was the farasah of the mumin.

Comment: "farasah of the mumin" literally means the (wisdom of a believer) , no eyes of Allah here . (Arabic speaker)

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35378/13438 is somewhat relevant.